# a problem with bot.login(token). what to do?

Tags: discord.js

I am new to coding in Discord.js and I have a problem. writes to me the error is the line that contains bot.login(token)

Could you tell me my mistake and explain how to fix it? thank you in advance.

writes to me: bot.login(token);
^

ReferenceError: bot is not defined
at Object. (C:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\FNaFRP-bot3.0\index.js:7:1)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m

here is the code itself

````
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { token } = require ("./config.json")
const prefix = '?'
const noperms = 'I dont think you have premission to do that!'
const norole = 'I dont think you have the right role to do that!'
bot.login(token);

bot.on('reddy', messgae => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is succefully on! in ${bot.guilds.size} Servers and in ${bot.channels.size} channels.`)
})

bot.on('message', function(message){
    if (message.mentions.users.first() --- bot.user) {
        message.channel.send('My prefix is \'?\'')
    }
})


bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'help' :
        if(!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Test Role')) return message.channel.send(norole) 
        message.channels.send('My prefux is \'?\' ').then(msg => {
            msg.react('✅')
        })
    }
})

bot.on('message', message=>{
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'clear' :
        message.delete();
        if(!message.nomber.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send(noperms)
        if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Please provide a number.')
        message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]).then ;{
            message.channel.send('- Succefully Deleted').then(msg => {
                msg.react("✅")  
        })
        console.log(`${message.author.username} deleted ${args[1]} messages in ${message.channel.name}`)
    }
}
})```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move **bot.login(token);** to the bottom of your code
you can't login untill your code is all down

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const { token } = require ("./config.json")
const prefix = '?'


// other code

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 3):

your client is `client` and not `bot` you could either change the
`const client = new Discord.Client();` to `const bot = new Discord.Client();` or replace all the `bot.` with `client.`

**EDIT**: Fixed other Errors in the Code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const { token } = require ("./config.json")
const prefix = '?'
const noperms = 'I dont think you have premission to do that!'
const norole = 'I dont think you have the right role to do that!'
bot.login(token);

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is succefully on! in ${bot.guilds.cache.size} Servers and in ${bot.channels.cache.size} channels.`)
})

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.mentions.users.first() == bot.user) {
        message.channel.send('My prefix is \'?\'');
    }
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'help' :
        tr = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Test Role').id;
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.has(tr)) return message.channel.send(norole);
        return message.channel.send('My prefix is \'?\' ').then(msg => {
        msg.react('✅')});
        case 'clear' :
            message.delete();
            if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send(noperms)
            if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Please provide a number.')
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]).then ;{
                message.channel.send('- Succefully Deleted').then(msg => {
                    msg.react("✅")  
            })
            console.log(`${message.author.username} deleted ${args[1]} messages in ${message.channel.name}`)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: it started but for some reason does not respond to commands